# Should I use "mul" or "imul" when multiplying a signed number to an unsigned number?

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, unsigned, signed

I have found out that both `mul` and `imul` can be used to multiply a signed number to an unsigned number.

For example:

```
global _start

section .data
    byteVariable DB -5

section .text
_start:

mov al, 2
imul BYTE [byteVariable]
```

You can replace `imul` with `mul`, and the result would still be the same (`-10`).

Are `mul` and `imul` exactly the same when multiplying a **signed** number to an **unsigned** number, or is there a difference between them?

Comment: No, the result is not the same, presumably you just checked the low half of the result only and that is the same. The unsigned `mul` should produce `502` as result in `ax`.

Comment: @Jester You are right, `ax` is `0x01F6`  (`502`) when using `mul`, and `0xFFF6` (`-10`) when using `imul`.

Comment: Always use `imul reg, r/m32` or `imul reg, r/m32, imm` if you don't need the high-half result; it's more efficient on modern CPUs (1 uop) because it doesn't have to write the high half anywhere.  https://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: Related: [Why is imul used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607/8528014)

Answer (score 4):

The upper half is different, as mentioned in the comments. If you don't care about the upper half, you can use either `mul` or `imul`, in all of their forms (the one-operand forms produce the upper half, but in this scenario you would ignore it).

If you do care about the upper half, neither `mul` nor `imul` works by itself, since they just multiply unsigned*unsigned and signed*signed, but you can fix it fairly easily.

Consider that a signed byte has the bit-weights -128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 while an unsigned byte has the bit-weights **+**​128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1. So you can represent the unsigned value of `x` in signed format (I know this is confusing but it's the best I can do) as `x + 256 x_7` (where `x_7` is bit 7 of `x`). The easiest way to see is probably to split it: `x + 2 * 128 * x_7`. What's happening here is compensating for the -128 weight, first removing it by adding the value of bit 7 128 times and then going all the way up to the +128 weight by doing it again, of course this can be done in one step.

Anyway, multiplying that by some signed number `y` and working it out gives `256 x_7 y + xy`, where `xy` is the (double-width) result of `imul` and `256 x_7 y` means "add `y` to the upper half if the sign of `x` is set", so a possible implementation is (not tested)

```
; al has some unsigned value
mov dl, al
sar dl, 7
and dl, [signedByte]
imul BYTE [signedByte]
add ah, dl
```

Naturally you could sign-extend one operand, zero-extend the other, and use a 16 bit multiplication (any, since the upper half is not relevant this way).

Answer (score 1):

x86 *does* have an instruction that multiplies signed bytes by unsigned bytes: [SSSE3 `pmaddubsw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmaddubsw).

You can think of it as sign-extending one operand to 16 bits, zero-extending the other to 16 bits, then doing an NxN -> N-bit multiply.  (For each SIMD element).

It also horizontally adds pairs of word products from adjacent bytes, but if you unpack the inputs with zeros (`punpcklbw` or `pmovzxbw`) then you can get each product separately.

Of course if you have SSE4.1 then you could just `pmovsxbw` one input and `pmovzxbw` the other input to feed a regular 16-bit `pmullw`, if you don't want pairs added.

---

**But if you just want one scalar result, `movsx` / `movzx` to feed a regular non-widening `imul reg, reg` is your best bet.**

As Harold points out, `mul r/m` and `imul r/m` widening multiplies treat both their inputs the same way so neither can work (unless the signed input is known to be non-negative, or the unsigned input is known to not have its high bit set, so you can treat them both the same after all.)

mul and imul also set FLAGS differently: CF=OF= whether or not the full result fits in the low half.  (i.e. the full result is the zero-extension or sign-extension of the low half).  For `imul reg,r/m` or `imul reg, r/m, imm`, the "low half" is the destination reg; the high half isn't written anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Another behavior of flags. For MUL: OF=CF=1 when carry bit changes upper half; For IMUL: OF=CF=1 when carry bit changes sign bit in low part (or just sign bit in result for 2 or 3 operands form)

Comment: That's not a very clear description.  Intel's manual explains it better: [`mul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul) sets CF and OF if the upper half is non-zero.  [`imul`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) sets CF and OF if the upper half isn't the sign-extension of the low half.  Otherwise they're cleared.  So in both cases CF=OF = whether or not the result fits in the low half.  (The 2 and 3 operand forms of `imul` *only* produce the low half of the full multiply, but flags are still set the same as the one-operand form.)