# Assembly X86, Segmentation Fault When Dividing

Tags: function, assembly, x86-64

I am receiving a segmentation fault with the following fragment of code which, I cannot figure out why it would throw a segmentation fault if when doing multiplication it worked as it should. The code is essentially communicating with both the asm and c file to display certain information such as the sum, average, min, max, and multiplication / division for the certain data that is being entered. Below is my fully coded library which has the functions that will be called.

*The main issue is when dividing*

Here is the following code to show my division process:

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
getStatsExtended:
    ; rdi array of bytes
    ; rsi is a quadword with the value being the number of elements in the array
    ; rdx is the address of a quadword to store the max
    ; rcx is the address of a quadword to store the min
    ; r8  is the address of a quadword to store the sum of the numbers
    ; r9  is the address of a quadword to store the average of the numbers
    ; Stack parameter 1 min*max the minimum number mulitiplied times the maximum
    # Stack parameter 2 max/min the maximum number divided by the minimum number

    ;prologue
    ; push the rbp value to the stack
    ;TBD
     push rbp
    ; save the stack pointer into rbp
    ; TBD
    mov rbp, rsp
    ; save any registers that will be used for calculations
    ; TBD
    push r12
    push r13
     
    ; max
    mov r15, rsi ; set the counter to start at the last value in the array
   
    mov rax, 0x0
    mov al, byte [rdi+r15-1]
    nextMaxE:
    dec r15
    cmp r15, 0x0
    jbe MaxE
    cmp al, byte [rdi+r15-1]
    jb greaterE
    jmp nextMaxE

    greaterE:
    mov al, byte [rdi+r15-1]
    jmp nextMaxE    

    MaxE:
    push rax ; put the value on the stack to pick up later

    ; min
    mov r15, rsi ; set the counter to start at the last value in the array
   
    mov rax, 0x0
    mov al, byte [rdi+r15-1]

    nextMinE:
    dec r15
    cmp r15, 0x0
    jbe MinE
    cmp al, byte [rdi+r15-1]
    ja lesserE
    jmp nextMinE

    lesserE:
    mov al, byte [rdi+r15-1]
    jmp nextMinE

    MinE:
    push rax ; put the value on the stack to pick up later
   
    ; sum
    mov r15, rsi ; set the counter to start at the last value in the array
   
    mov rax, 0x0
    mov al, byte [rdi+r15-1]

    nextSumE:
    dec r15
    cmp r15, 0x0
    jbe SumE
    mov r14b, byte[rdi+r15-1]
    add rax, r14
    jmp nextSumE

    SumE:
    push rax ; put the value on the stack to pick up later
   
    ; ave
    push rdx
    mov rdx, 0x0
    div rsi
    mov qword[r9], rax ; set the return value for ave
    pop rdx
   
    ; pull values from the stack
    pop qword [r8]      ; sum
    pop qword [rcx]     ; min
    pop qword [rdx]     ; max
   
    ; multiply min times max return in 7th parameter
    ; TBD
     mov rax, qword[rcx] ; moving into rax min
     imul qword[rdx] ; multiplying by rdx
     
     mov r12, qword[rbp+16] ; Setting r12 to addres of 7th parameter
     mov qword[r12], rax        ; setting value of rax (mul result) to 7th parameter
     
   
    ; divide max by min return in 8th parameter
    ; TBD
    mov rax, qword[rdx] ; moving max into rax
     xor rdx, rdx           ; zeroing out rdx
    div qword[rcx]           ; dividing by min
   
    call printRAX
   
    mov r13, qword[rbp+24] ; setting r13 to the address of 8th parameter
    mov qword[r13], rax       ; setting value of rax (div result) to 8th parameter
   
    ;epilogue
    ; pop the saved registers
    ; TBD
    pop r13
    pop r12
   
    ; pop the rbp
    ; TBD
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail what this code is supposed to do?  How is the caller expected to set up registers/memory when calling it, and how does the caller expect to have results returned?  If it's meant to follow C calling conventions, could you provide its declaration, and perhaps equivalent C code?

Comment: You should read carefully the descriptions of what the `mul` and `div` instructions do, in particular how they affect `rdx`.  Following `mul`, you no longer have the pointer value in `rdx` that you did before.

Comment: @NateEldredge is there a way to keep the value of rdx the same to be re used in the division?

Comment: You can use two-operand `imul` instead which doesn't widen.  However you still have to zero `rdx` before dividing, like you did previously.

Comment: @NateEldredge tried doing imul and tried zeroing out rdx by doing `xor rdx, rdx` before dividing but still get seg fault

Comment: Show the new code, please.

Comment: Your code still uses one-operand imul, not `imul rax, [rdx]` (like I commented on your previous question: [Attempting to store and return a mul and div value](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/119030837)). Read the manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul) and single-step your code in a debugger.

Comment: There's a canonical answer about how to (not) use one-operand mul/imul, to avoid clobbering RDX when you don't care about the high half of the 128-bit product: [Why is imul used for multiplying unsigned numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607)