# Why do x86 mul and div instructions only take a source operand?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, instruction-set, instructions

In x86 assembly, most instructions have the following syntax:

```
operation dest, source
```

For example, `add` looks like

```
add rax, 10 ; adds 10 to the rax register
```

But mnemonics like `mul` and `div` only have a single operand - `source` - with the `destination` being hardcoded as `rax`. This forces you to set and keep track of the `rax` register anytime you want to multiply or divide, which can get cumbersome if you are doing a series of multiplications.

I'm assuming there is a technical reason pertaining to the hardware implementation for multiplication and division. Is there?

Comment: `imul` has some additional forms that are less cumbersome. It's [not just for signed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42587607/555045) multiplication. More recently there is also `mulx`, which required innovation in instruction encoding.

Comment: Related: [problem in understanding mul & imul instructions of Assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1948058) shows the `imul rsi, rdi` non-widening form without any implicit operands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The destination register of `mul` and `div` is not `rax`, it's `rdx:rax`.  This is because both instructions return two results; `mul` returns a double-width result and `div` returns both quotient and remainder (after taking a double-width input).

The x86 instruction encoding scheme only permits two operands to be encoded in legacy instructions (`div` and `mul` are old, dating back to the 8086).  Having only one operand permits the bits dedicated to the other operand to be used as an extension to the opcode, making it possible to encode more instructions.  As the `div` and `mul` instructions are not used too often and as one operand has to be hard-coded anyway, hard-coding the second one was seen as a good tradeoff.

This ties into the auxillary instructions `cbw`, `cwd`, `cwde`, `cdq`, `cdqe`, and `cqo` used for preparing operands to the `div` instruction.

Note that later, additional forms of the `imul` instruction were introduced, permitting the use of two modr/m operands for the common cases of single word (as opposed to double-word) multiplication (80386) and multiplication by constant (80186).  Even later, BMI2 introduced a VEX-encoded `mulx` instruction permitting three freely chosable operands of which one source operand can be a memory operand.

Comment: Some of the multi-operand `imul` forms date back to the 186.

Comment: @ecm Corrected!